# Mutators for Objection.js model

Tags: node.js, objection.js

Is it possible to set mutators for the model?

```
class MyModel extends Model {
  set email(email) {
     this.email = email ? email.toUppercase() : null;
  }
}
```

This code becomes a recursive call. How is the preferable way to handle it?
I want to set email column to null if it is empty string.

Or should I use the `$beforeInsert` and `$beforeUpdate` hooks?

Comment: I think you may want to look at setting default values https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#default-values... please note: I have never used objection.js but Schema are always a good thing when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: I changed muito question. It was missing the transform to uppercase

Comment: I've had this issue and followed others advice of creating an "inbetween" property on the class that you can get and set from without it recurring, but the issue is that it includes any properties on the class as being a database column and breaks if it doesn't exist (eg, creating `this._email`, it will say "no such `_email` column) ... I'm still baffled.